# SAS - Survey Select - Selecting Different Sample Size per Stratum

Tags: sas, sampling

I have a list of financial advisors and I need to pull 4 samples per advisor but catch is in those 4 samples I need to force 2 mortgages, 1 loan, 1 credit card lets say.

Is there a way in the Survey select statement to set the specific number of samples to pull per stratum? I know you can stratify on 1 category and set it as a equal number. I was hoping I could use a mapping of employee names + the number of samples left to pull for each category and have survey select utilize that to pull in a dynamic way.

I'm using this as an example but this only stratifies on employee first and gives me 4 per employee. I would need to further stratify on Product type and set that to a specific sample size per product.

```
proc surveyselect data=work.Emp_Table_Final
   method=srs n=4 out=work.testsample SELECTALL;
   strata Employee_No;
run;
```

Thanks i know it might sound complicated, but if i know its possible then i can google the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a dataset be the target of the `n` option.  That dataset must:

- Contain the strata variables as well as a variable `SAMPSIZE` or `_NSIZE_` with the number to select
- Have the same type and length as the strata variables
- Be sorted by the strata variables
- Have an entry for every strata variable value

See the [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyselect_sect011.htm) for more details.

```
data sample_counts;
length sex $1;
input sex $ _NSIZE_;
datalines;
F 5
M 3
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by sex;
run;

proc surveyselect n=sample_counts method=srs out=samples data=class;
strata sex;
run;
```

For two variables it's the same, you just need two variables in the sample_counts.  Of course it makes it a lot more complicated, and you may want to produce this in an automated fashion.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by sex age;
run;

data sample_counts;
length sex $1;
input sex $ age _NSIZE_;
datalines;
F 11 1
F 12 1
F 13 1
F 14 1
F 15 1
M 11 1
M 12 1
M 13 1
M 14 1
M 15 1
M 16 0
;;;;
run;

/* or do it in an automated way*/

data sample_counts;
  set class;
  by sex age;            *your strata;
  if first.age then do;  *do this once per stratum level;
    if age le 15 then _NSIZE_ = 1;  *whatever your logic is for defining _NSIZE_;
    else _NSIZE_=0;
    output;
  end;
run;



proc surveyselect n=sample_counts method=srs out=samples data=class;
strata sex age;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for this that helps with the product selection. Now how do i stratify on two variables? The first would have to be the lender, then next would be what you posted the products. If i just use the method above, i would have to split the dataset into 1 data set per lender to do what I need to do.

Comment: @mitoKon Stratifying on two variables is the same as stratifying on one variable - just use two variables.

Comment: Hi Joe thanks for your amazing help. Solved all my questions.